# Psql still throws "query has no destination for result data" even with "return query"

Tags: sql, postgresql, psql

I have a plpgsql function looking like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION func1(....)
RETURNS TABLE(aa integer, bb integer, cc timestamp) 
AS $BODY$
BEGIN
  CREATE TEMPRORAY TABLE tmp 
  AS SELECT .....;

  WITH RECURSIVE x AS (
    SELECT * 
    FROM tmp 
    WHERE some stuff ...)
  SELECT * 
  FROM tbl1 
  WHERE ....;
END;
$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

It throws an exception when I call it as `select func1(1, 2, 3)` being

```
ERROR:  query has no destination for result data
HINT:  If you want to discard the results of a SELECT, use PERFORM instead.
```

However, inserting `return query` into the body  doesn't help either:

```
return query
WITH RECURSIVE x AS ( ....)
```

and the error remains the same.

Comment: Works for me. You need to show more of your function for us to spot where the bug is.

Answer (score 0):

`RETURN QUERY` should fix the problem so your problem is probably elsewhere.

One major point though is that creating temp tables in functions has some really unfortunate implications (it is really easy to run into lock exhaustion problems due to the fact that temp tables get locked).  You would do *MUCH* better to move that inline in your query.

Secondly, chances are this may be a different `SELECT` statement than the one you think.  PL/PGSQL sometimes throws errors referring to the end of the function so you need to look through the whole function for your error.  So obfuscate the code if you need to but the best we can do at present is say "your error is probably elsewhere.  Please double check."

Answer (score 0):

show this example, it works

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION test()
  RETURNS TABLE(_id integer, _name text) AS
$BODY$
BEGIN

    return QUERY
    with x as (select id,name from my_table)
    select id,name from x;

END;$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql STABLE
```